# How to declare constraint correctly

Tags: c#

I have a class `RuleCondition<TValue>`:

```
public class RuleCondition<TValue>
{
    public string PropertyToCheck { get; private set; }

    public TValue Value { get; private set; }

    public RuleCondition(string propertyToCheck, TValue value)
    {
        PropertyToCheck = propertyToCheck;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

In the `Rule<T>` class I have a field which holds an instance of it:

```
public abstract class Rule<T>
{
    private readonly string mPropertyName;
    private readonly object mError;
    private readonly RuleCondition<TValue> mCondition;

    protected Rule(string propertyName, object error, RuleCondition<TValue> condition)
    {
        mCondition = condition;
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I now want to add my `RuleCondition<T>` to a `Rule` (which inherits from `Collection<Rule<T>>` and `DelegateRule<T>`inherits from `Rule<T>`) like this

```
Rules.Add(new DelegateRule<ConnectionSettingsViewModel>(nameof(Username),
          "Username: Cannot be empty, starting with a space or a backslash.",
          x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Username),
          new RuleCondition<LoginOptions>(nameof(LoginUsage), LoginOptions.Instrument)));
```

I get an error that the type doesn't match, which is correct. My problem is now: how to get the `TValue` for the `RuleCondition` whitout having to declare it at the "top" and break all my code. It feels somehow wrong to have the constraint declared everywhere just to get it at the `RuleCondition<TValue>` class.

Is there an easier way? What do I miss?

**EDIT:** `T` is already of type `*ViewModel`.

I think I have to add more explanation:

The "chain" starts here:

```
public class ConnectionSettingsViewModel : NotifyDataErrorInfo<ConnectionSettingsViewModel>
{ }
```

If I would now add the `TValue` constraint to the `Rule` class like so `Rule<T, TValue>`, I also need to provide that constraint to the `NotifyDataErrorInfo` class. So to the "top" class. But that feels wrong. To have that constraint declared in every class in between the `NotifyDataErrorInfo` and the "last" class `RuleCondition`.

**EDIT 2:**
I took the code from [here](https://rehansaeed.com/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-part4-inotifydataerrorinfo/) to implement a control validation to my MVVM application. But I figured I need some conditions to be met for several controls. So that a rule won't be "executed" everytime, but just if a specific `RadioButton` e.g. is checked.

Comment: I think `private readonly RuleCondition<TValue> mCondition;` needs to be `private readonly RuleCondition<T> mCondition;` so it will use the `T` that the class was declared with.

Comment: Can't be, because `T` is already of type `*ViewModel`. I need another constraint to get the `TValue`. But if I add that like `Rule<T, TValue>` I get errors that a several places I have to provide that type. Which makes sense. But it feels wrong to have it declared at so many places, just to get it at `RuleCondition<TValue>` class.

Comment: Do you need to know the `Type` of the `Value` property when you process conditions? Can you work with the `object` instead?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan I thought about that. But then I have to use some reflection to get the type. I need to have at least the `TValue` to be an `enum` and to be `bool`.

Comment: What is the connection between `NotifyDataErrorInfo<ConnectionSettingsViewModel>` and `Rule<T>`, does it inherit it?

Comment: `NotifyDataErrorInfo<ConnectionSettingsViewModel>` holds a `RuleCollection` which inherits from `Collection<Rule<T>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your input and that blog post, you can do something like this. Take into account that you'll need to slightly adapt classes presented in that blog.

First, you can create `ConditionalRule<T, TValue>` which inherits the `DelegateRule<T>` (or any other `Rule<T>` you want). *For this, you'll need to unseal `DelegateRule` class*

```
public class ConditionalRule<T, TValue> : DelegateRule<T>
{
    public TValue Value { get; private set; }

    public ConditionalRule(string propertyName, object error, Func<T, bool> rule, TValue value)
        : base(propertyName, error, rule)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override bool Apply(T obj)
    {
        // do your business driven condition check before calling
        return base.Apply(obj);
    }
}
```

Secondly, you must extend `RuleCollection<T>` with additional generic method:

```
public sealed class RuleCollection<T> : Collection<Rule<T>>
{
    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new <see cref="Rule{T}"/> to this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property the rules applies to.</param>
    /// <param name="error">The error if the object does not satisfy the rule.</param>
    /// <param name="rule">The rule to execute.</param>
    public void Add(string propertyName, object error, Func<T, bool> rule)
    {
        this.Add(new DelegateRule<T>(propertyName, error, rule));
    }

    public void AddConditional<TValue>(string propertyName, object error, Func<T, bool> rule, TValue value)
    {
        this.Add(new ConditionalRule<T, TValue>(propertyName, error, rule, value)
    }

    //....
    #endregion
}
```

Furthermore, you'll need to adapt your code which adds rules into collection, depending on the rules you want to add:

```
Rules.AddConditional<LoginOptions>(
    new ConditionalRule<ConnectionSettingsViewModel, LoginOptions>(
        nameof(Username),
        "Username: Cannot be empty, starting with a space or a backslash.",
        x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Username),
        LoginOptions.Instrument
    )
);
```

Please note, I didn't check the code so you can expect some compile time issues, but the general idea would be to create specific rules out of `Rule<T>` using inheritance. That way, each rule will nicely fit into `RuleCollection<T>`

Comment: Thanks Darjan, will check that out!

Comment: Bodgan I do had to tweak it a bit. But no I got it to work. The rule will be applied only if a condition is met. Thanks again!

Comment: @FredM Glad to hear that! :)